# Can't remote from windows 10

Tags: windows-10, vpn, remote-desktop

I installed windows 10 Pro from disc, I am currently running into a problem where I cannot remote out of my Windows 10 machine. I can remote into it from anywhere in the house, but cannot remote out. 
I cannot remote into my wife's PC, my Surface 3 or my laptop. Each of these 3 devices can remote into each other perfectly fine. Wife's PC in Win7, Surface 3 and my laptop are both 8.1. I have had Windows 10 for a few months now, and I now need it to work on my desktop as it has 2 large monitors, and I have to work from home over the weekends. And I prefer not to use my laptop with a small screen.

I have tried disabling Firewall, enabling RDP through the firewall, and I have no idea what else I can try, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: let me make sure i got this right, you need to use RDP on your windows 10 box to connect to a remote computer,  but it's failing for some reason. however when you try to connect to that same remote server from one of your other computers it works just fine right? is it giving you any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

It just says that the remote access to the server is not enabled, the remote computer is turned off, or the remote computer is not available on the network.

Which, I know it is turned on as I am sitting right next to it. Remote access is enabled, as other devices I own can remote into it no issues. And it is on the same workgroup on the same network.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! On this Q&A site we try to provide [good answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) to questions people ask. It seems you did not attempt to answer the question in your answer. Instead, you asked another question. This does not fit in [our model](https://superuser.com/help/stackexchange) since the answer section is reserved for answers to the asked question. Please [submit a new question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) instead.